Query Timeout error for DE with 600M records
We have a Backup log DE with Data spreading for 4yrs with around 600M records.
When i trying to Query a DE with filters like date ,status..the query fails with the timeout error. I tried to use the filter and also the random split still it doesnt work. filter and randomsplit didnt create any segemented DE from it.
i did check the log DE and there are no null values for subscriber or emailaddress.
tried with query studio,automation query and automation activity..all the cases it fails.
The query is select count subscriberkey,eventdate from [Log_DE] where year(eventdate) = '2023'.
The query is select count subscriberkey,eventdate from [Log_DE] where year(eventdate) = '2023' and status ='Active'
the query fails with the timeout error.
Can you please help me with any trick to query this DE with 600M records.
I logged a case with Salesforce but they are telling we need to do some custom coding in the org as its a huge load on the servers and it will be billed.

See here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/327075/5202

You can try the following non-coding strategies:

Break Down the Query
Year-Month Split: Modify your WHERE clause to further filter by month in addition to the year. This could significantly reduce the amount of data processed in each query.

Use Data Extracts
Data Extract Activities: Instead of querying directly in SQL, consider using Data Extract Activities to pull smaller, more manageable segments of your DE into a CSV or another format. This can then be re-imported into a new DE with reduced data volume.

Schedule Queries During Off-Peak Hours
Step-by-Step Process:
Identify Off-Peak Hours: Determine when your Salesforce Marketing Cloud environment is least busy (e.g., late night or early morning).
Schedule Automation: Use Automation Studio to schedule your SELECT queries during these off-peak hours. This reduces the server load and the likelihood of encountering timeouts.
Monitor Execution: Monitor the scheduled queries to ensure they complete successfully without timeouts.

Archive Older Data
Step-by-Step Process:
If possible, archive older data into another DE or external storage system. This will reduce the size of your Log_DE and improve query performance.


